# nginxのurl書き換え機能は、どう変換されたかクライント側からわかるのか

Tags: nginx

nginxのurl書き換え機能は、どう変換されたかクライント側から分かりますか？

Comment: 「url書き替え機能」といのは[`rewrite`ディレクティブ](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)を使用した機能のことですか？

Comment: はい。その機能です。

Comment: そんなことをクライアント側が知る必要はなくて、逆に変換規則がわかってしまうと攻撃者の手助けになるので「わからない」のが答えなのでは？